# Google Wallet, add back of pass

Tags: wallet, google-wallet

I can't find how to add additional information to the back of my card in Google Wallet.
In Apple Wallet, in any case, this can be done and there are a lot of examples, but on Google I can’t even find an article with a description.

Those examples that exist are clearly not enough https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-android#9

I am also interested in what file format should be used in the application to create a map. On Apple I use .pkpass for this.

[image]

I searched on the codelabs website and Google